# How to run a NodeJS script with RUST_BACKTRACE=1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust

I'm trying to run [this Node script](https://github.com/xdk2mam/xdk2mam/tree/master/ble-sdcard/xdk2mam-nodejs) on a couple of Raspberry Pis. It runs smoothly on the Pi3 but on a Pi Zero I get this error:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'destination and source slices have different lengths', libcore/slice/mod.rs:695:9
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I  tried to run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1 node script.js` but the error output is the same.

I've searched for hours how to run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` to get some debug information but I find only discussions where is not specified how to use the command.

Both Raspberry boards have the last Raspbian Lite version installed and on the Pi Zero I have a fresh installation.

Comment: If you don't know much about Rust, and especially if you didn't write the Rust code in question, the backtrace is very unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: You aren't using Rust directly, and I couldn't find where Rust is used in the project you linked. I would have to guess that one of the project dependencies itself has a dependency on a module that uses Rust. You'd probably have to change code in _that_ module to change how the Rust executable is run.

Comment: You could try adding `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` as a system environment variable on the pi, and just remember to remove it after?

Comment: Added RUST_BACKTRACE=1 as env variable to ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, /etc/profile  (checked with env command) and did a reboot but the error output is still the same...not sure if I'm missing something about setting system variables on the pi

Comment: Another hypothesis: the rust code might be in an executable spawned by JS code, in which caes the parent environment could be incorrectly passed to the child process (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12986 for example)